# ServiceStack: Update<T>(...) produces 'duplicate entry'

Tags: servicestack

I have tried reading the docs, but I don't get why the Update method produces a "Duplicate entry" MySQL error.

The docs says

> In its most simple form, updating any model without any filters will update every field, except the Id which is used to filter the update to this specific record:

So I try it, and pass in an object, like below. A row with id 2 already exists.

```
using (var _db = _dbFactory.Open())
{
    Customer coreObject = new Customer(...);
    coreObject.Id = 2;
    coreObject.ObjectName = "a changed value";
    _db.Update<Customer>(coreObject); // <-- error "duplicate entry"
}
```

Yes, there are options using .Save and such, but what am I missing with the .Update? As I read it, it should  use its Id property to update the row in the db, not insert a new row?

[image]

Comment: I don't see how it's possible for `db.Update()` to create a duplicate record since it only performs an `UPDATE` which only updates records not inserting new ones, so I'm assuming you're mistaken. If you can update your question with stand-alone example (i.e. include `Customer` class) I'll run it locally to see if I can repro it.

Comment: I have actually updated the GIT repo with a stand-alone example, including the classes. In this case, I had breakpoints, so I could lift execution inside to just test an update to see how it worked. I ahve updated the question above with a screenshot, showing the error.

Comment: that example shows you're calling `Save()` not `Update()` that your question indicates. What's the Filename that contains the stand-alone example?

Comment: Save? No, its shows _db.Update, line 54. Or what do you mean?

Comment: the Save  method is my own method, I could have called it "DonaldDuck<T>" =)

Comment: I do an Insert on line 39, then break, then I move the execution into whatever I want to test, in this case to line 52 to do an Update...

Comment: Your question shows a code example which calls `Update()` but your debugging the `Save()` method?

Comment: Forget about the name of my method =) I call it "Save", but its irrelevant, we can call it "Test" or whatever. The important thing is line 54 and the error it gave =)

Comment: So this isn't OrmLite's Update API??  You need to make that clearer in your question which should be self-descriptive not rely on hidden implementation (which in this case is misleading).

Comment: yes, ofc its OrmLite, otherwise I would not tag it in the question or have a title starting with "ServiceStack" etc. This is ServiceStack OrmLite, where I use the Update method on the db variable. I have updated the image, so its no longer called Save =)

Comment: Time for me to head off to bed. I updated the same GIT repo again, that has the latest of these tests. laters =)

Comment: Can you add `OrmLiteConfig.BeforeExecFilter = dbCmd => Console.WriteLine(dbCmd.GetDebugString());` at the start to see what SQL is being generated as OrmLite only generates an UPDATE so that API can't be inserting duplicate rows.

Comment: Here it is (updated): https://pastebin.com/EKhC2wN2

Comment: So, it is an UPDATE... "UPDATE `Customer` SET `Id`=@Id, `PopulationRegistryNumber`..." with parameters "PARAMS: @Id=10008, @PopulationRegistryNumber=1IUTSMFS0M..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with this method is that you're updating a generic object `T` but your Update API says to update the Concrete `Customer` type:

```
public void MyTestMethod<T>(T coreObject) where T : CoreObject
{
    long id = 0;
    using (var _db = _dbFactory.Open())
    {
        id = _db.Insert<T>(coreObject, selectIdentity: true);

        if (DateTime.Now.Ticks == 0)
        {
            coreObject.Id = (uint)id;
            _db.Delete(coreObject);
        }
        if (DateTime.Now.Ticks == 0)
        {
            _db.DeleteById<Customer>(id);
        }
        if (DateTime.Now.Ticks == 0)
        {
            coreObject.Id = (uint)id;
            coreObject.ObjectName = "a changed value";
            _db.Update<Customer>(coreObject);
        }
    }           
}
```

Which OrmLite assumes that you're using a different/anonymous object to update the customer table, similar to:

```
db.Update<Customer>(new { Id = id, ObjectName = "a changed value", ... });
```

Which as it doesn't have a WHERE filter will attempt to update all rows with the same primary key.

What you instead want is to update the same entity, either passing in the Generic Type `T` or have it inferred by not passing in any type, e.g:

```
_db.Update<T>(coreObject);
_db.Update(coreObject);
```

Which will use OrmLite's behavior of updating entity by updating each field except for Primary Keys which it instead used in the `WHERE` expression to limit the update to only update that entity.

#### New Behavior in v5.1.1

To prevent accidental misuse like this I've added an Update API overload in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/abc1c3d62ba6235aea104f97757f173bbd870d05) which will use the Primary Key as a filter when using an anonymous object to update an entity, so your previous usage:

```
_db.Update<Customer>(coreObject);
```

Will add the Primary Key to the WHERE filter instead of including it in the SET list. This change is available from v5.1.1 that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Comment: Thanks for that mythz, first class support for ServiceStack! I hope my tests will go well so I can upgrade and start using it in production =) regards